# ComboBox with two or more sections

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

### Summary

Is it possible to use two panels in `ItemsPanelTemplate` of a `ComboBox`, where items are added to one of those panels depending upon a property value of the item? For example a `WrapPanel` at the top and a `StackPanel` below it. An item would go to `WrapPanel` if Property `IsCustom` is `True` and to the `StackPanel` otherwise.

### Details

So this is what I have achieved:

[image]

and this is what I now want:

[image]

That is, I need to divide the **dropdown part** of my ComboBox into two or more sections.

If I understood things correctly, I have to edit `ItemsPanelTemplate` of my `ComboBox` and define a custom one, but when I did that, I found there was a `StackPanel` (I was expecting a `ListBox`) with its `IsItemsHost` set to `True`, which if I understand correctly, directs generated items to the `StackPanel`. In this scenario, how do I add two sections here? Which controls do I use? How do I define `IsItemsHost` on those controls?

Googling returns a lot of results that divide the dropdown into columns, but none that divides it into rows.

Comment: create custom Template for ComboBox and change DropDown content in there

Comment: @ASh: That's what I am doing. But what do I do therein? Which `Panel`s do I use? How does the parent `ItemsControl` know which `Panel` gets a particular item? Which one do I set `IsItemsHost` on? Thought I explained that in the question.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no simple way to do that. There is only one `ItemContainerGenerator` in an `ItemsControl`. You have to create your own control that handles things in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox" Height="20">
    <ComboBox.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ComboBox.GroupStyle>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle x:Name="Rect" Width="10" Height="10" Fill="{Binding Brush}"/>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Brush}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter TargetName="Rect" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
</ComboBox>
```

Code-behind for testing:

```
    public class BrushData
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public Brush Brush { get; set; }

    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var lists = new List<BrushData>
        {
            new BrushData {Type = "Theme", Brush = Brushes.Red},
            new BrushData {Type = "Theme", Brush = Brushes.Blue},
            new BrushData {Type = "Theme", Brush = Brushes.Orange},
            new BrushData {Type = "Standard", Brush = Brushes.LightGreen},
            new BrushData {Type = "Standard", Brush = Brushes.LightPink},
            new BrushData {Type = "More Colors...", Brush = null}
        };

        var collection = new ListCollectionView(lists);
        collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Type"));

        MyComboBox.ItemsSource = collection;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. That solves half of the problem. Do you see a way of choosing different panel for each group? (First group needs to use a `WrapPanel` while the second one should use default `StackPanel`)

Comment: I didn't find a way to use different panel for each group. As a workaround, I used `WrapPanel` for my items and made the items in the first group wide enough to make the next item go to the following line, thus creating a `StackPanel` look. Not ideal, but works for me.